# Running a bash script on dropped files

Tags: bash, shell, applescript

I have a bash script that works as intended if I run it through the command line but I would like to have it run on dropped files files via an Automator Droplet.

The script loops through the files and places every file that has the same substring before the "-" in the same folder.

Here is the bash script:

```
for file in *; do dir=$(echo $file | cut -d- -f1); mkdir -p $dir; mv $file $dir; done
```

Through the Terminal I can set the directory and it works flawlessly but going through Automator I am having a hard time getting it to work.
I have tried wrapping it inside an Applescript that takes dropped files as an input but it does not seem to work and I'm not quite sure where it is failing.

```
on open droppedItems
    repeat with aFile in theFiles
        do shell script "do dir=$(echo $file | cut -d- -f1); mkdir -p $dir; mv $file $dir; done"
    end repeat
end open
```

I also tried this which I though was supposed to let you take the arguments and generate a list on which to execute the commands.

```
for arg in [list]; do dir=$(echo $file | cut -d- -f1); mkdir -p $dir; mv $file $dir; done
```

Comment: Try debugging by putting `display dialog aFile` inside your loop. Try also checking your current working directory so you know where your subdirectory will be created.

Comment: If you are using a **Automator** _workflow_ saved as an _application_ for _drag_ and _drop_ and _shell scripting_ is the primary coding, then why are you using a **Run AppleScript** _action_? Use a **Run Shell Script** _action_ with **Pass input: [as arguments]** instead!

Comment: I tried using the Run Shell Script with Pass input: [as arguments] as well as the Run AppleScript. I

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks I'll give this a try

Comment: I see absolutely no good reason to be using **AppleScript** to run _shell script commands_ here when it can all be done in a **Run Shell Script** _action_ with **Pass input: [as arguments]**. You are only adding a needless layer of complexity trying to wrap the _shell script code_  in **AppleScript**!

Comment: I agree that would be a cleaner way to do it the problem I am having is the default directory is always being used as the input. If i set the directory manually the script works. I just need a way for the bash script to accept the files dropped as arguments which it currently is not doing even if I have that selected. @user3439894

Comment: If I set the directory like this it works, but preferably I would want the directory to be selected by the user

Comment: cd Desktop/Test

for file in *; do dir=$(echo $file | cut -d- -f1); mkdir -p $dir; mv $file $dir; done

Comment: Clarification: do you want the user to drop the *files* to be moved on it, or to drop a *directory* and have the files inside that directory get moved?

Comment: @Gordon Davisson, based on the _code_ presented in the OP and based on what's said, it _files_ not _folders_ that are the _target items_ been dropped.  I accidentally wrote the answer up as a  _Service/Quick Action_ however it also works as an **Automator** _application_ for _drag_ and _drop_ of _files_ and made a note of it.  I was working on another question referencing a _Service/Quick Action_ at the time and confused the two. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'd *code* the *shell script* for the **Run Shell Script** *action* with **Pass input: [as arguments]** in the **Automator** *workflow* used as a *Service/Quick Action*<sup>1</sup>:

*Example* **shell script** *code*:

```
    # f  = fully qualified pathname
    # d  = directory pathname
    # fn = filename with extension
    # dn = portion of filename up to - and
    #      the dir to create, if necessary.

for f in "$@"; do
    [ -f "${f}" ] || continue
    d="${f%/*}"
    fn="${f##*/}"
    dn="${fn%-*}"
    cd "${d}" || exit
    [ ! -d "${dn}" ] && mkdir "${dn}"
    mv -n "${f}" "${dn}"
done
```

---

[image]

---

**Notes**:

- The `-n` *option* used in the `mv` *command* stops from overwriting an existing *file*. If you have a scenario where you want existing *files* overwritten, then remove the `-n` *option* used in the `mv` *command*.
- <sup>1</sup> The *example* **shell script** *code* can also be use in an **Automator** *workflow* as an *application* for *drag* and *drop* operations. Just select **Application** when creating a new *workflow* and add the **Run Shell Script** *action* with **Pass input: [as arguments]** and the *code*.